# Python: how to create network of collaboration from pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, social-networking

I have a DataFrame like the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Item':['A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C','C'], 
    'Name': ['Tom','John','Paul','Tom','Frank','Tom', 'John', 'Richard', 'James'],
    'Total':[3,3,3,2,2,4,4,4,4]})

print df

Item Name  Total
A    Tom     3
A    John    3
A    Paul    3
B    Tom     2 
B    Frank   2
C    Tom     4
C    John    4 
C    Richard 4 
C    James   4
```

I want to create a network of collaboration which is normalized over the `Total` collaborations between two pairs and the number of `Name` on the same `Item`. At end I would like something like

```
df1 

Name     Name1     Item       Total 
 Tom     John        A          3
 Tom     John        C          4
 Tom     Paul        A          3
 Tom     Frank       B          2
 Tom     Richard     C          4 
 Tom     James       C          4
 John    Paul        A          3
 John    Richard     C          4
 Richard James       C          4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this gets what you want.  I used [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group by the `Item` that connects two Names and [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) within the group.

```
cnxns = []
for k,g in df.groupby('Item'):
    [cnxns.extend((n1,n2,k,len(g)) for n1,n2 in combinations(g['Name'], 2))]

pd.DataFrame(cnxns, columns=['Name', 'Name1', 'Item', 'Total'])

    Name    Name1   Item    Total
0   Tom     John        A   3
1   Tom     Paul        A   3
2   John    Paul        A   3
3   Tom     Frank       B   2
4   Tom     John        C   4
5   Tom     Richard     C   4
6   Tom     James       C   4
7   John    Richard     C   4
8   John    James       C   4
9   Richard     James   C   4
```

Probably a better method out there, but this should do what you ask.

The only difference between my output and your desired output is that I included `(John, James, C, 4)`, but maybe you wanted that (assuming I understood the question correctly)?

Comment: It is: however total could change. Is it possible to take the value reported in the column instead of the sum?

Comment: You could change `len(g)` to `g['Total'].iloc[0]`, which will take a value from the original DataFrame.  If that's what you're after I'll edit the answer?